# glue to connect localstack s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, localstack

I'm creating glue for local development following the concept mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html).
I'm using `localstack` along with `glue spark using Jupyter lab`
As you can see below the screenprint, from my spark jupyter lab, I can able to connect to localstack s3 it's bucket and contents.
[image: localstack s3 connection via jupyterlab]
Jupyter lab is created using
`docker run -it -v ${PWD}/local_path_to_workspace/:/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace/ -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummyaccess -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummysecret -e AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 -e DISABLE_SSL=true -e ENDPOINT_URL="http://localstack-glue:4566" --rm -p 4040:4040 -p 18080:18080 -p 8998:8998 -p 8888:8888 --name glue_jupyter_lab amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01 /home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh`  to start the jupyter lab.

however, if I use below commands to access my localstack s3 bucket inside jupyter lab:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate()) 
inputDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://glue-localstack-bucket-person/persons.json"]}, format = "json")
```

I'm getting access denied error.

```
An error occurred while calling o73.getDynamicFrame.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3://glue-localstack-bucket-person/persons.json: getFileStatus on s3://glue-localstack-bucket-person/persons.json: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: WGKYX9DAMXQF1P20; S3 Extended Request ID: Kvpk7Ri77fkrtmzeTCZv+VGoD1dfHUgbXdihVfXxTWlXLIb/vfU+y11jZPiFMGol2F+6sXqGUmw=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: Kvpk7Ri77fkrtmzeTCZv+VGoD1dfHUgbXdihVfXxTWlXLIb/vfU+y11jZPiFMGol2F+6sXqGUmw=:403 Forbidden
```

So my question is how can I change session configuration to refer local stack endpoint with dummy access key and secret key?

Answer (score 2):

The breakthrough moment here is in the discovery that the `ENDPOINT_URL` environment varible doesn't have any effect on the mechanisms inside the `GlueContext` class.

That is, changing the `ENDPOINT_URL` to `http://localstack-glue:4566` doesn't stop the `create_dynamic_frame_from_options` method from trying to access a bucket called `glue-localstack-bucket-person` out there on the public internet. I believe you're seeing a 403 because you're trying to access a real bucket called `glue-localstack-bucket-person` on the real S3 network - for which you likely do not have access. Even if you owned the bucket and had access, your dummy values for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and  `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` would lock you out.

The parameter you need to modify is `fs.s3a.endpoint`, deep in the hadoop configuration. You can use a helper function similar to this to create the correct configuration for your local Glue setup:

```
def create_pyspark_session_to_localstack():
    print('creating pyspark session')
    sparksession = (SparkSession.builder
                    .master('local[2]')
                    .appName('glue-connect-to-localstack')
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate())

    hadoop_conf = sparksession.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
    hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3a.enableV4", "true")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "mock")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "mock")
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", "mock")

    # set fs.s3a.endpoint here!
    hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localstack-glue:4566")


    return sparksession
```

This function replaces your call to `SparkContext.getOrCreate()`. You might use it like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from adaptors.localstack import create_pyspark_session_to_localstack
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

glueContext = GlueContext(create_pyspark_session_to_localstack()) 

inputDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://glue-localstack-bucket-person/persons.json"]}, format = "json")
```

That should do the job.

---

Full credit goes to Raj on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/development-testing-etl-pipelines-aws-locally-kamal-k/